# Training Error for Activity Classification in CreateML

Tags: machine-learning, createml

[image]I am trying to train an activity classification model using CreateML.

When I click 'train,' I get a training error that reads:

"Training activity classification requires Intel HD 515 Graphics or later."

I'm using a MacBook Air from mid 2012. Is this just a hardware limitation? If so, what are some other options? Appreciate any help or advice you have, thank you.

Comment: Yes indeed! It doesn't work on my Mac Air 2015 as well. Perhaps should work on the newer ones after 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create ML** framework requires `macOS 10.14 or above.` Check this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml).

[image: Screenshot 1]

This framework also requires **Intel HD 515 Graphics or later** in order to work. I’ve `Intel UHD graphics (Ultra HD) and is working fine.`

[image: Screenshot 2]

In your case *MacBook Air mid 2012 is compatible for Create ML framework*. However, you need to `switch to better graphics card on Mac or try using external graphics processing unit with your Mac.`

Check this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/create-ml/)

[image: Screenshot-3]